# Why can't @var.setter function access class variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, setter

I have a class where I want to validate the data whenever it's property is changed. I wish to store the valid options as a class variable that the setter can refer to, but I seem to have found that *within the `@var.setter`* option I'm *unable to reference any class variables at all*.

Why is that?

Code example:

```
class Standard():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 2

  @property
  def variable1(self):
      # This works
      print(self.variable2)
      return self.__variable1

  @variable1.setter
  def variable1(self, var):
      # This doesn't work
      print(self.variable2)
      self.__variable1 = var

x = Standard()
print(x.variable1)
x.variable1 = 4
print(x.variable1)
```

This outputs:

```
AttributeError: 'Standard' object has no attribute 'variable2'
```

When it clearly does.

Comment: `self.variable2` doesn't yet exist when you assign to `self.variable1`.

Comment: Do you intentionally set `self.variable1` in `__init__`? Or do you mean `self.__variable1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **first** setting `variable1` in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.variable1 = 1
    self.variable2 = 2
```

Since `self.variable1` is handled by `@variable1.setter`, `variable2` can't yet exist at that time. You could *swap* the two lines:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.variable2 = 2
    self.variable1 = 1
```

Now `variable2` is properly set before `variable1.setter` runs.

Alternatively, give `variable2` a class attribute to act as a default:

```
class Standard():
    # ...

    variable2 = 'class default'

    @variable1.setter
    def variable1(self, var):
        print(self.variable2)
        self.__variable1 = var
```

or use `getattr()` on `self`:

```
@variable1.setter
def variable1(self, var):
    print(getattr(self, 'variable2', 'not available yet'))
    self.__variable1 = var
```

or set `__variable1` directly, bypassing the setter:

```
class Standard():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__variable1 = 1  # don't use the setter
        self.variable2 = 2
```

Comment: Wow, You taught me so much! Thank you!